# octave name change for multiple files

Tags: matlab, file, directory, octave, rename

I need to read file names like 0.100004; 1.19996 etc, change str to num, round it up or down to one decimal place (0.1; 1.2), save it and do it for all files in a directory.

Is there any easy way to do it? Should I use readdir functionality?
Thanks you in advance!
EDIT:
I did it:

```
A = glob ("*.******")  
for idx = 1:numel(A)  
    element = A(idx)  
    typeinfo (element)  
    e = cell2mat (element)  
    typeinfo (e)  
    e = str2num (e);  
    roundb (e)  
    rename (A(idx) , e)  
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. `readdir` or `glob` might be used to read the list of files, then iterate over the list, change the filename with `rename`

Comment: @Andy

A = glob ("*.******")  //
    for idx = 1:numel(A)  //
        element = A(idx)  //
        typeinfo (element)  //
        e = cell2mat (element)  //
        typeinfo (e)  //
        e = str2num (e);  //
        roundb (e)  //
        rename (A(idx) , e)  //
    end  //




I have troubles with changing that cell to numeric //
(// - enter) //
Sorry I do not know how to format my reply... ;F

Comment: please edit your question instead of putting code into the comments. much easier to read that way.

Comment: @Nick J 
Ok, thanks I will keep in mind.